# Unable to render animation with audio

Tags: rendering, audio

I'm completely stuck on trying to render with audio. I've made sure the audio codec is selected alongside FFMPEG, I've added the audio file in the video editor and I can hear the music when playing the scene but every time I render anything, I get no sound.

Any ideas please? I'm using blender 2.82

thanks,
Sal

Answer (score 1):

Have you selected an audio codec for your output? Default is "No Audio"[image: select codec here]

Edit:
Ok, I just saw that you seem to have enabled a codec... Have you tried different codecs? Maybe you chose one that is not supported on your media player?

Alternatively: Have you tried re-importing the output video strip into blender?

Comment: yeah, i've tried aac and mp3. i've tried importing into da vinci and there's no audio at all. i've also tried re-importing into blender. not sure what else to try!

Comment: What happened when you re-imported it? Was there a sound track?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Oh yeah, there's sound and I can play the animation with sound, this is why I'm confused. Anyway, I'm not too bothered as I can simply import the audio post with da vinci, so easy enough. Still a little annoying though as I'm not sure what else I can try

Answer (score -1):

I was having the same problem. The solution comes from Richard Antalik,developer.blender org
'Enable Sequencer in Output Properties > Post Processing panel.'

In case you are not familiar with things. (in Blender 3.0 at least) The Output Properties (tab) is where you define the size of your output, where to output your file to, encoding for video and audio, etc. You will also find in the same tab the Post Processing panel with compositing and sequencer check boxes. Put a *Check on the sequencer*
Good luck.